# Idris2 syntax for symbol types

Tags: syntax, symbols, idris

[In the Idris 1 documentation, `'foo` is given as the syntax to create a symbol type: an empty type identified with its name](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/effects/state.html#id3):

> Here, we have used a symbol type. In general `’name` introduces a new
> symbol, the only purpose of which is to disambiguate values

The [Idris 2 documentation on changes compared to Idris 1](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/updates/updates.html#) doesn't mention symbol types at all, so that should suggest that they work as before. However, Idris2 chokes on symbol types with a parse error. For example:

```
public export
Html : Type -> Type
Html a = Node 'Html a
```

> Couldn't parse declaration (next tokens: `[identifier Html, identifier a, symbol =, identifier Node, Unrecognised ', identifier Html, identifier a, export, interface, identifier HtmlAllAttribute]`)

What is the new syntax for symbol types?

Comment: You could try making an issue on GitHub or asking on the Idris Slack